# iMac Target Display Mode

Tags: display

I am trying to go into target display mode on my iMac. Its a 2012 iMac which does support TDM. However, I don't have a standard iMac keyboard because I bought a refurbished Mac which comes with a different keyboard & mouse. That being said, I can't use the Command + F2 key combination to go into TDM. How am I able to without doing that?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried all the [steps recommended by Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204592)?

**Use Target Display Mode**

Follow these steps to start using your iMac as a display:

1. Make sure that your iMac is turned on, and the other Mac is logged in to a macOS user account.
2. Connect the Mini DisplayPort or Thunderbolt cable between the two computers.
3. Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> on the keyboard of the iMac that you want to use as a display.
   After you press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, your iMac displays the desktop from the connected Mac.

**If <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> doesn't work**

If your iMac doesn't switch to Target Display Mode when you press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, check these things:

- Make sure that the iMac you're trying to use as a display supports Target Display Mode.
- Target Display Mode works only when your primary Mac is logged in to a macOS user account. For example, if your first Mac is at the FileVault login screen, pressing <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> on your iMac does not enable Target Display Mode. You must first log in to your Mac (using a regular display, if necessary) before you can use an iMac in Target Display Mode.
- Make sure that you're pressing <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> on the keyboard that's connected to the iMac you want to use as a display.
- In Keyboard System Preferences, if the checkbox is enabled for "Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys," the key combination changes to <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>.
- Make sure that your Mini DisplayPort or Thunderbolt cable is connected to both computers.
- If you're currently logged in on the iMac you want to use as a display, try logging out to return to the login window. Then press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> again.
- Some older Apple keyboards and third-party keyboards might not allow <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to toggle display modes. If this happens, use the keyboard that came with your iMac to toggle Target Display Mode on and off.
- If your iMac is currently started up in Windows, it won't enter Target Display Mode. Target Display Mode isn't supported in Boot Camp.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a keyboard set up for Windows, EG a Windows logo key to the left and/or right of the space bark **That** is your <kbd>Command</kbd> key.

So pressing <kbd>Windows</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that Function Keys are turned on in Settings - Keyboard, like this:

[image]